# Angular 2 compiled to ES5 in visual studio 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, angular

How do I compile Angular 2 in Visual Studio 2015 into ECMAscript 5, so it runs in any browser without needing any runtime library (like Traceur)?

Comment: Have you looked at the [5 Min Quickstart in JS](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) (TypeScript + Dart also provided)?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was very usefull. In addition the following article helped me get the compiling working in Visual Studio:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1026938/AngularJS-Getting-Started-with-Visual-Studio